# congruent to 1 mod p

Tags: gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory, characteristic-p

This is a somewhat vague question: for a prime number *p*, we often see that various counts come out to be 1 modulo *p*. What are the possible reasons for this?

Here are some I've encountered:

1. For some reason, the counting can be reduced modulo *p*, or in the field of *p* elements, and in that setting, the answer turns out to be 1.
2. There is a group action of a *p*-group on the set with exactly one fixed point. Hence, all the other orbits have sizes equal to a power of *p*. This is used, for instance, in proving that the number of *p*-Sylow subgroups is congruent to *1* mod *p*.
3. A kind of inductive counting argument, that is based on the following observation: the sum of *a* numbers, each of which is 1 mod *p*, is congruent to *a* mod *p*. Thus, the sum is 1 mod *p* iff *a* is *1* mod *p*. This comes up, for instance, in inductive proofs that the number of subgroups of order $p^k$ in a group of order $p^n$ is congruent to 1 mod $p$. A more general version of this is Phillip Hall's Enumeration Theorem. (This argument can be viewed as a variant of (1), but I find it sufficiently distinctive to mention separately).
4. The number comes up as the number of one-dimensional subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space over a field with *p* elements, which we know is a polynomial in *p* with constant term *1*.
5. More sophisticated combinations of (3) and (4) are used to prove that the number of subgroups of various kinds in *p*-groups is congruent to 1 mod *p*. See, for instance, the work of Jonah and Konvisser: *Counting abelian subgroups of p-groups: a projective approach*, *Journal of Algebra*, Page 309-330, 1975.
6. An application of Fermat's little theorem or a related "order in the multiplicative group" result, wherein a prime *q* distinct from *p* can divide $(a^p - 1)/(a - 1)$ only if it is congruent to 1 mod *p*.
7. Some results on Euler characteristics in combinatorics. I don't really understand how they're proved, or why the "congruent to 1 mod p" comes up.

Looking forward to more situations where "1 mod p" comes up, and/or further insights into the ways I've already mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

The Chevalley-Warning theorem is proved this way, you count mod p using Fermat's little theorem. Except you show the number of solutions is divisible by p, and if you have a trivial solution then you have another.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley-Warning_theorem

Comment: You can make this a "1 mod p" statement: If d<=n, then the number of F_p-points on a hypersurface of degree d in P^n over F_p is 1 mod p.  This can be given a cohomological interpretation and generalized to other classes of varieties, as in recent work of Hélène Esnault and others.

Answer (score 3):

If $p\lt q$ are primes, then there is a non-abelian group of order $pq$ if and only if $q$ is 1 (mod $p$).

Comment: And one implication of this follows from the third Sylow theorem
as mentioned by the OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $R_n$ be the number of reduced Latin squares of order $n$.  Then $R_n \equiv 1 \pmod n$ if $n$ is prime and $R_n \equiv 0 \pmod n$ if $n$ is composite.  See our paper [Divisors of the number of Latin rectangles](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2009.03.019).

In this case, when $n=p$ is a prime, this is arrived at via a group action (by a group of cardinality $p$) that has $(p-2)!$ fixed points.  Wilson's Theorem implies $(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$, giving the result.